# How can I view my MySQL database created by Entityframework 6

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I use Entity framework 6 and MySQL 5.5

When I use code first to create the my sql database, the database is created successfully, but when I open mysql workbench, I can't find it in MySQL workbench.

I have used EF 5.0 code before to create a database and the database can be found in MySQL workbench.

has anyone met this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bet an arm and a leg you haven't configured EF correctly an it is using it's default database instead of mysql, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773051/entity-framework-4-code-first-where-is-my-database) or [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

The easiest way to verify that is to shut down your MySQL server and test if your can still query your database with EF or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, @SchlaWiener. you are right. do you know how to config EF 6 to create db in mysql?